# Gerrit Register New Email 500 Error

Tags: java, debian, jetty, gerrit, turnkeylinux.org

I have just setup gerrit 2.12.4 on a turnkey revision control 14.1 and when I try the Register New Email feature I receive a 500 Internal Error.
I receive the following error message in the error_log and don't know how to interpret it.

Here is the config:

```
[gerrit]                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        basePath = /srv/repos/git/gerrit2/                                                                                                                                                                         
        canonicalWebUrl = http://revision-control:7900/                                                                                                                                                            
[database]                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        type = mysql                                                                                                                                                                                               
        hostname = localhost                                                                                                                                                                                       
        database = reviewdb                                                                                                                                                                                        
        username = gerrit2                                                                                                                                                                                         
[index]                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        type = LUCENE                                                                                                                                                                                              
[auth]                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        type = OPENID                                                                                                                                                                                              
[receive]                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        enableSignedPush = false                                                                                                                                                                                   
[sendemail]                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        enable = true                                                                                                                                                                                              
        smtpServer = smtp.office365.com                                                                                                                                                                            
        smtpServerPort = 587                                                                                                                                                                                       
        smtpUser = email@email.com                                                                                                                                                                             
        smtpEncryption = ssl                                                                                                                                                                                       
        sslVerify = false                                                                                                                                                                                          
[container]                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        user = gerrit2
        javaHome =  /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre                                                                                                                                                          
[sshd]                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        listenAddress = *:29418                                                                                                                                                                                    
[httpd]                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        listenUrl = http://*:7900/                                                                                                                                                                                 
[cache]                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        directory = cache
```

I suspect the process fails way before the smtp authentication.
I have checked the java path and it seems to be in order.

I have also given full permission to gerrit2 on both the java folder and the gerrit folder.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
[2016-09-07 20:55:23,439] [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector : Started ServerConnector@4a9829f1{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:7900}                                                                         
[2016-09-07 20:55:23,440] [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server : Started @20499ms                                                                                                                          
[2016-09-07 20:55:23,442] [main] INFO  com.google.gerrit.pgm.Daemon : Gerrit Code Review 2.12.4 ready                                                                                                              
[2016-09-07 20:56:54,864] [HTTP-50] WARN  org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler : Error for /accounts/self/emails/test@email.com                                                                  
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError                                                                                                                                                                              
        at com.google.gerrit.server.mail.OutgoingEmail.add(OutgoingEmail.java:384)                                                                                                                                 
        at com.google.gerrit.server.mail.RegisterNewEmailSender.init(RegisterNewEmailSender.java:49)                                                                                                               
        at com.google.gerrit.server.mail.OutgoingEmail.send(OutgoingEmail.java:92)                                                                                                                                 
        at com.google.gerrit.server.account.CreateEmail.apply(CreateEmail.java:134)                                                                                                                                
        at com.google.gerrit.server.account.CreateEmail.apply(CreateEmail.java:101)                                                                                                                                
        at com.google.gerrit.server.account.CreateEmail.apply(CreateEmail.java:42)                                                                                                                                 
        at com.google.gerrit.httpd.restapi.RestApiServlet.service(RestApiServlet.java:328)                                                                                                                         
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)                                                                                                                                            
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doServiceImpl(ServletDefinition.java:287)                                                                                                                   
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:277)                                                                                                                       
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:182)                                                                                                                         
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)                                                                                                                
        at com.google.gerrit.httpd.GetUserFilter.doFilter(GetUserFilter.java:82)                                                                                                                                   
        at com.google.gwtexpui.server.CacheControlFilter.doFilter(CacheControlFilter.java:73)                                                                                                                      
        at com.google.gerrit.httpd.RunAsFilter.doFilter(RunAsFilter.java:117)                                                                                                                                      
        at com.google.gerrit.httpd.AllRequestFilter$FilterProxy$1.doFilter(AllRequestFilter.java:136)                                                                                                              
        at com.google.gerrit.httpd.AllRequestFilter$FilterProxy.doFilter(AllRequestFilter.java:105)                                                                                                                
        at com.google.gerrit.httpd.RequestContextFilter.doFilter(RequestContextFilter.java:75)                                                                                                                     
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:119)                                                                                                                
        at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$1.call(GuiceFilter.java:133)                                                                                                                                      
        at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$1.call(GuiceFilter.java:130)                                                                                                                                      
        at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$Context.call(GuiceFilter.java:203)                                                                                                                                
        at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:130)                                                                                                                                    
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)                                                                                                                 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)                                                                                                                              
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)                                                                                                                       
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)                                                                                                                      
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)                                                                                                                               
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)                                                                                                                        
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)                                                                                                                       
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)                                                                                                                           
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)                                                                                                                          
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:95)                                                                                                                    
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)                                                                                                                          
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)                                                                                                                                                 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)                                                                                                                                       
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)                                                                                                                             
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)                                                                                                                              
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)                                                                                                                        
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)                                                                                                                         
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)                                                                                                                                                                   
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can only invoke this method before calling getInstance                                                                                                                 
        at org.apache.commons.validator.routines.DomainValidator.updateTLDOverride(DomainValidator.java:1680)                                                                                                      
        at com.google.gerrit.server.mail.OutgoingEmailValidator.<clinit>(OutgoingEmailValidator.java:24)                                                                                                           
        ... 41 more        
[2016-09-07 20:56:54,866] [HTTP-50] ERROR com.google.gerrit.pgm.http.jetty.HiddenErrorHandler : Error in PUT /accounts/self/emails/test@email.com                                                     
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError                                                                                                                                                                              
        at com.google.gerrit.server.mail.OutgoingEmail.add(OutgoingEmail.java:384)                                                                                                                                 
        at com.google.gerrit.server.mail.RegisterNewEmailSender.init(RegisterNewEmailSender.java:49)                                                                                                               
        at com.google.gerrit.server.mail.OutgoingEmail.send(OutgoingEmail.java:92)                                                                                                                                 
        at com.google.gerrit.server.account.CreateEmail.apply(CreateEmail.java:134)                                                                                                                                
        at com.google.gerrit.server.account.CreateEmail.apply(CreateEmail.java:101)                                                                                                                                
        at com.google.gerrit.server.account.CreateEmail.apply(CreateEmail.java:42)                                                                                                                                 
        at com.google.gerrit.httpd.restapi.RestApiServlet.service(RestApiServlet.java:328)                                                                                                                         
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)                                                                                                                                            
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doServiceImpl(ServletDefinition.java:287)                                                                                                                   
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:277)                                                                                                                       
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:182)                                                                                                                         
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)                                                                                                                
        at com.google.gerrit.httpd.GetUserFilter.doFilter(GetUserFilter.java:82)                                                                                                                                   
        at com.google.gwtexpui.server.CacheControlFilter.doFilter(CacheControlFilter.java:73)                                                                                                                      
        at com.google.gerrit.httpd.RunAsFilter.doFilter(RunAsFilter.java:117)                                                                                                                                      
        at com.google.gerrit.httpd.AllRequestFilter$FilterProxy$1.doFilter(AllRequestFilter.java:136)                                                                                                              
        at com.google.gerrit.httpd.AllRequestFilter$FilterProxy.doFilter(AllRequestFilter.java:105)                                                                                                                
        at com.google.gerrit.httpd.RequestContextFilter.doFilter(RequestContextFilter.java:75)                                                                                                                     
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:119)                                                                                                                
        at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$1.call(GuiceFilter.java:133)                                                                                                                                      
        at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$1.call(GuiceFilter.java:130)                                                                                                                                      
        at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$Context.call(GuiceFilter.java:203)                                                                                                                                
        at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:130)                                                                                                                                    
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)                                                                                                                 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)                                                                                                                              
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)                                                                                                                       
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)                                                                                                                      
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)                                                                                                                               
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)                                                                                                                        
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)                                                                                                                       
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)                                                                                                                           
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)                                                                                                                          
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:95)                                                                                                                    
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)                                                                                                                          
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)                                                                                                                                                 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)                                                                                                                                       
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)                                                                                                                             
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)                                                                                                                              
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)                                                                                                                        
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)                                                                                                                         
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)                                                                                                                                                                   
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can only invoke this method before calling getInstance                                                                                                                 
        at org.apache.commons.validator.routines.DomainValidator.updateTLDOverride(DomainValidator.java:1680)                                                                                                      
        at com.google.gerrit.server.mail.OutgoingEmailValidator.<clinit>(OutgoingEmailValidator.java:24)                                                                                                           
        ... 41 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems it was a bug in the 2.12.4 gerrit build. I received some help from the [gerrit forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/repo-discuss/RWvdXR-Z4nA/1USSK1F6AAAJ).

Issue and fix:

```
Fix usage of OutgoingEmailValidator to make sure TLD override works

The call to DomainValidator.updateTLDOverride may only be done before
the call to EmailValidator.getInstance otherwise it throws an exception.

Putting the DomainValidator.updateTLDOverride call inside a static
block doesn't seem to be safe enough. Protect it with an atomic boolean
instead.
```

[The bug](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/#/c/85710/) was fixed and is awaiting merge in future builds.